# routing problem under Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, routing

I've looked around the net for two days, but no solution found, therefor I ask my question here:

I'd like to connect my WD MyBook NAS to my MacBook.
I've reconfigure the NAS to use a static IP (10.146.45.61) instead of DHCP.
I use the IP range 10.146.45.x for all of my devices.
The MacBook is connected via WLAN (10.146.45.62, en1) to my home network, namely to the internet router (10.146.45.1).
I like to connect the MacBook and the NAS directly via ethernet cable due to performance reasons via the following steps:

1) I deactivate AirPort at the MacBook
2) I've manually add the direct route from the macbook, via ethernet cable device, to the NAS:

```
route -n add -host 10.146.45.61 -interface en0
```

result) The NAS became available (ping, smb), fine I thought.

remark) at this time, the wlan router (and the whole internet) aren't available ... of course :-)

Then I activate the AirPort again, the router becomes available again (and the internet) but the NAS isn't available any more. There is a routing problem and I can't solve it. Here is my routing table (via netstat -rn)

```
default            10.146.45.1        UGSc          123        2     en1
default            link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0
10.146.45/24       link#5             UCS             4        0     en1
10.146.45/24       link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0
10.146.45.1        0:30:bf:1:cd:62    UHLWI         134      595     en1   1195
10.146.45.20       127.0.0.1          UHS             0      229     lo0
10.146.45.61       d4:9a:20:b8:4b:d8  UHLS            0        2     en0
10.146.45.62       127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
10.146.45.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       14     en1
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              4     1004     lo0
169.254            link#5             UCS             0        0     en1
```

I flush the routes and reboot several times ... no success.
I switch the order of the network services in the system configuration ... no success.

What's wrong with my configuration ?

Thanks in advance
Dominik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem here is that you have

```
 10.146.45/24       link#5             UCS             4        0     en1
 10.146.45/24       link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0
```

Which is claiming that 10.146.45.* is reachable over BOTH en1 and en0, and I'm guessing that OSX is picking the first one because it's first in the list.  Naturally if you get it to change the order so en0 has priority, the internet will stop working.

The Right Thing To Do is to make en0 a completely different network with completely different addresses (I vote 10.146.46.*) instead of trying to pretend that it's the same network.

Otherwise, change the netmask on en0 to 255.255.255.252 (using the .62 address)  This will make the en0 network be 10.146.45.60/30 which will be more specific than the 10.146.45/24 network and should therefore be used for addresses from 10.146.45.60-63 (don't allow the DHCP server to issue those addresses on the *real* network)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so.. by the looks of things.. en1

```
default            10.146.45.1        UGSc          123        2     en1
is your default Gateway
```

Your route to your device is going down.. en0

```
10.146.45.61       d4:9a:20:b8:4b:d8  UHLS            0        2     en0
```

Remove the route from the table using

```
route -n delete -host 10.146.45.61
```

This might work.. i hope :D

Comment: possible check the same on your other devices..

Can other devices ping the NAS.. or is it only your Mac?

Comment: the default gateway mentioned above is the WLAN based route to the internet, so it's necessary to stay connected and can't be deleted.

Comment: Only the Mac should ping the NAS

Comment: Ok im confused to what you want :P